# Limiting data so I don't get a circular reference exception

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to figure out how to limit the fields recalled from a related sub table in a linq query. In this example the events table. The events table has a relationship back to the contact so when I try to serialize this for return as json it errors with a circular reference exception. How would I go about only pulling the information from events without pulling the references back to contact?

```
var data = (from c in Contacts
            .Where(a => a.LastName.Contains("Smith"))
            let pa = c.Addresses.Where(a=>a.AddressType.Name.Contains("Primary")).FirstOrDefault ()
            let e= c.Events.Take(5).OrderByDescending (x =>x.DateTime )             
            select  new
            {
                c.Id,
                value = c.LastName + ", " + c.FirstName ,
                Street1 = pa.Street1,
                Street2 = pa.Street2,
                City = pa.City,
                State = pa.State,
                PostalCode = pa.PostalCode,                   
                , Events= e
            })
            .Take(10).ToArray()
```

Comment: Did you try projecting events into a simpler set of objects?

Comment: That's what I'm struggling with. Just learning Linq

Comment: Do you want the 'Contacts' included in the serialization of the 'Events' in the context of this code? If you never want them included you could add a 'JsonIgnore' attribute to the property in question.

Comment: I'm assuming your using the 'Newtonsoft.Json' library.

Comment: If its the 'JavaScriptSerializer' then you would add the 'ScriptIgnore' attribute.

Comment: It's actually the output of an MVC JSonResult method. Yes to the Newtonsoft.Json library. I tried JsonIgnore which did not work.